# How can I validate if string is numeric and/or one character "." is allowed

Tags: c++, string, iterator, numeric

I am trying to validate if string has numeric or not. I want to see if string has character or more that are not allowed such as not numeric and/or one character "."

my codes are

```
//this code is call function (is_number). sTempArray[3] is amount such as $00.00
if(!is_number(sTempArray[3]))
{
    cout << "Your amount have letter(s) are not allowed!;
}

//the is_number is function and will run if anyone call this function.
bool MyThread::is_number(const string& data)
{
    string::const_iterator it = data.begin();
    while (it != data.end() && std::isdigit(*it))
    {
        ++it;
    }
    return !data.empty() && it == data.end();
}
```

I want to validate the string is allowed. For example, string has a value, it is 500.00 and it will be allowed but it always be denied because period character is in the string. Another example, string has a value, it is 500.00a and it should be not allowed.

Comment: *string has a value, it is 500.00 and **it will be allowed but it always be denied** because period character is in the string* - I don't understand what you mean. Is that a valid string or not? Can you please post a few example strings and indicate clearly whether each is valid or invalid?

Comment: You can use strtod and test the end pointer (if your number format and the format used in strtod are the same)

Comment: sorry for confusion.. If sTempArray[3] have value. The value is "500.00". The is_number function will recognize char such as "." and return it as invalid. It suppose be valid because "." supposed be allowed. Another example, if sTempArray[3] have value and it is "50a0.00". The is_number function will recognize two char such as "a" and "." and return them as invalid. However, "a" is invalid and "." is invalid BUT it supposed be valid/allowed

Comment: @Daniel "`If sTempArray[3] have value. The value is –`" is still very confusing. Can you please provide concrete examples as @Praetorian asked? Also consider using [std::stod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop of your is_number function you could add an `if` statement to check if the the current iteration is a digit or to check if it is a "." in it (and maybe add a boolean value to check wether there was only one "."?).

It would look something like this:

```
bool MyThread::is_number(const string& data)
{
    string::const_iterator it = data.begin();
    while (it != data.end())
    {
        if (std::isdigit(*it) || it == "."){
          ++it;
        }

    }
    return !data.empty() && it == data.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean flags if dot and digit was already met and modify the loop:

```
bool MyThread::is_number(const string& data)
{
    bool dot_met = false, digit_met = false;
    for( string::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it )
    {
        if( is_digit( *it ) ) {
            digit_met = true;
            continue;
        }
        if( *it == '.' ) {
           if( !digit_met || dot_met ) return false;
           dot_met = true;
           continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return digit_met;
}
```

Function in this form will not accept number started with . (like .05 ) if you do want that, change is trivial. Alternatively you can use regual expressions library, with `"\\d+\\.?\\d*"` expression.